# The usage of commas with the word "additionally"

Tags: punctuation, commas, adverbs

Could you please tell me if one should opt to insert a comma before and after the word "additionally" in this sentence?

> Referring back to my school, it had a strong policy in terms of active life propaganda and, additionally, conducted a lot of well-organized sports clubs.

Comment: Sounding clumsy is a bigger problem than placement of commas. 'Also' seems a more natural choice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Can you please clarify what exactly sounds clumsy in your point of view?

Comment: I'd have to rewrite it, and I'd not attempt that without knowing the actual conditions. But as an example, a school having 'a strong policy in terms of [any sort of] propaganda' implies they tried to indoctrinate everybody, or censored everything related. 'Additionally' next to 'and' seems overkill (not that redundancy is wrong per se).

Comment: "Additionally" is in parenthesis in this sentence (you could put it in brackets) so surrounding it with commas is correct. It is similar to saying "My school, which I attended from age 11 to age 15, had a strong policy of promoting active living." You could leave out the part in commas without destroying the structure of the sentence, the commas make this clear.

Comment: @BoldBen, my sincerest thanks to you, sir

Answer (score 0):

The sentence does have problems but I am not sure that "additionally" is the significant one. In your sentence, "additionally" is a free modifier that fronts the clause, *"conducted a lot of well-organized sports clubs."* As, for example, in "**Unfortunately**, you have lost."

Fronting free modifiers are usually offset with a comma or commas.

In short, I would keep the comma.

Comment: Thanks for a vivid response!

Comment: I'd say the use of a comma after in 'My school had a strong policy as regards active life propaganda and, additionally, conducted a lot of well-organized sports clubs' or rather  'My school had a strong policy as regards active life propaganda, and additionally, conducted a lot of well-organized sports clubs' is non-standard. If forced to retain 'additionally', I'd use 'My school had a strong policy as regards active life propaganda, and additionally conducted a lot of well-organized sports clubs'. Substituting 'also' for 'additionally' (which seems a far better option) bars commas.

Comment: Searching some British news websites, it's usual to offset an initial "additionally" but it's rarely used after "and" in the way the OP wants (however it's commonly used to directly modify a verb). I did find from the Guardian in 1936 the following monster: "To detach Rumania from her agreement with Russia, and completely to undo the work of M. Titulescu, would, from the German view, be in itself a great triumph, and, **additionally**, a big step towards the bigger and remote goal of getting rid of the Franco-Russian Pact, if and when a favourable opportunity should occur..." Commas there.